# Applications of Borel Cantelli lemmas and almost sure bounds for a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, almost-everywhere, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Consider a sequence of probability measure $(P_{\theta,n})_{n=1}^\infty$ on $\mathbb{R}$, assume that $X_{n}$ is distributed according to $P_{\theta,n}$ and let $c_{\theta,n}$ be a diverging sequence of constants. Here $\theta$ can be thought of as a parameter. If 
$$
P_{\theta,n}(X_n/c_{\theta,n}>1)\lesssim n^{-\delta}
$$
for $\delta>1$, then, denoting by $P_{\theta,\infty}$ the law of the sequence $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, by Borel-Cantelli lemma 
$$
P_{\theta,\infty}( X_n/c_{\theta,n}>1, \, \text{i.o.})=0
$$
where $\text{i.o.}$ stands for infinitely often. **First question**: can we then conclude that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_{\epsilon, \theta}$ such that
$$
P_{\theta,\infty}( X_n/c_{\theta,n}<1+\epsilon, \, \forall n \geq n_{\epsilon,\theta})=1?
$$

Assume next that the parameter satisfies $\theta \in \Theta $ and that, in fact,
$$
\sup_{\theta \in \Theta }P_{\theta,n}(X_n/c_{\theta,n}>1)\leq \kappa n^{-\delta}
$$
for dome $\kappa>0$. **Second question**: can we then conclude that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $n_\epsilon$ such that
$$
\inf_{\theta \in \Theta }P_{\theta,\infty}( X_n/c_{\theta,n}<1+\epsilon, \, \forall n \geq n_\epsilon)=1?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is already negative, so $\theta$ is irrelevant. The Borel-Cantelli lemma grants a *random* $N$ such that
$$
P( X_n/c_{\theta,n}\le 1 \, \forall n \geq N)=1.
$$
However, this does not yield a non-random $N$, even in an "$\epsilon$-version".

Precisely, consider the infinite (fair) coin-flipping space, and let $X_n=n$ if the number of the first head is $n$ and $0$ otherwise; $c_{n}=\sqrt{n}$. Then, for $n\ge 2$, 
$$
P(X_n/c_{n} >1) = P(X_n=n)= 2^{-n}.
$$
However, for *any* $\epsilon>0$ and any (fixed, non-random) $N\ge 1$
$$
P( X_n/c_{n}<1+\epsilon, \, \forall n \ge N)<1.
$$

Comment: Yes, in fact this was my doubt. But I was wondering: are there situations in which a random $N$ can be in fact substituted by a large but deterministic $n$ or, in practice, this is never the case?

Comment: I would say it's not the case almost surely :)